# Can someone help identify the model/year of this car for me?

Tags: car, vehicle-identification

I have a picture but I don't recognize the model. It's got a very distinctive hatchback.[image]

Comment: What did they do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to be a late-model Chevy Trailblazer:

[image]

I'm going to also add that it's possibly a Hyundai Kona which looks strikingly similar.  I just saw one of these yesterday and this is what it looks like:

[image: Hyundai Kona]

After comparing both to your photo, I still think it's more likely the Chevrolet but I wanted to add this one as another possibility.

Comment: Maybe. The hood/fender intervact at the bottom of the A-pillar appears different. Too, the top of the front door panel in the "late-model Chevy Trailblazer" is straight all the way to the A-pillar, while the corresponding panel in the unknown vehicle appears to rise at the mirror location.

Comment: It's a different angle for sure but I have a friend with one of these and it struck me as a Trailblazer right off.  I think the all white model in the OP photo makes it look a bit different.  It's clearly a Chevrolet (look at the grill) but none of their other models come close to this one.  It's quite distinctive.